# Android NATIVE browser remote debug not working when using weinre or chrome

Tags: android, html, remote-debugging, weinre

I've been using weinre and chrome to remote debug the native browser on Android tablet (Android 4.2.2) and so far it's not working. Cannot find the target. When i use it with chrome,firefox and opera it functions fine.

File is locally placed in sd card, and accessed via file:///sdcard/wherever/file.html. I need a way to debug a webpage on a native browser. Thanks.

Comment: Could be a lot of things.  Might want to have a discussion over at the weinre google group - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/weinre

Initial guess sounds like it may be a runtime error in your JS, that is keeping weinre from connecting.  Unfortunately, very difficult to debug.

Comment: Is your problem solved yet?

Comment: Hi, the problem was not solved. The native browser was to dumb to be used for debugging. Instead i opted for drag and drop testing of a html page from pc to the device and monitor any inconsistencies.

Comment: One possible problem could be cors. I've made some modifications to weinre server to allow it: https://github.com/apache/cordova-weinre/pull/10. Anyway, it's not working with native android browser.

Comment: In fact in my case the problem is that systemjs is breaking the app and because of that weinre is not working. If I comment all the code regarding to systemjs then it works.